# Cassandra CQL request

Tags: select, cassandra

I have a little probleme with Cassandra performances when I use a select query with a condition, example:

```
SELECT name from Perso where age = 18
```

It takes too much time and when the table arrived to 1M rows, I got the `timedoutexception()`.

Can I use the pagination in this case? if yes how to use with the condition in a request?

Comment: What is the column family (table) schema and what API are you using?

Answer (score 0):

Cassandra is quick at where clauses if there is low cardinality (i.e. number of rows) in the data, and is notoriously slow when there is a high cardinality.

The [Cassandra docs](http://www.datastax.com/docs/0.7/data_model/cfs_as_indexes) suggest to use one column family to store data and one or more other cfs to act as an indexes for that data.

So for example for your issue you could have two column families - one for Person and another index column family to map an age to a list of names. You can query this second table using the age as the key, and have the list of names returned to you. You can then use the individual returned names to query whatever data you want in the Person column family.

Comment: [Slightly more up-to-date documentation](http://www.datastax.com/docs/1.0/ddl/indexes)